# How to invoke HSQLDB DatabaseManager Swing app in JavaFX Swingnode?

Tags: java, swing, hsqldb, openjfx

I am trying to embed the HSQLDatabaseManager Swing App in my own JavaFX project.

```
public class SQLTool extends Application {

@Override
public void start (Stage stage) {
    final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

    createSwingContent(swingNode);

    StackPane pane = new StackPane();
    pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

    stage.setTitle("Swing in JavaFX");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 800, 600));
    stage.show();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
}

private void createSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            DatabaseManagerSwing dbms = new DatabaseManagerSwing();
            panel.add(dbms);
            swingNode.setContent(panel);
        }
    });
}
```

Getting a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
Looks like the jar file couldn't be found. It's placed under resources/lib/sqltool. I am using latest JDK14.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add Java version to your question. The error means it cannot find the SQLException class in JRE Java libraries.

Comment: I added that I am using latest JDK14 in my question. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: How come that the SQLException class cannot be found???

Comment: I don't know why SQLException cannot be found. This is probably a JavaFX issue